# Authenticate user and add them DB simultaneously

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase

I want to signup new users (through auth) and then add them (with their names and other info) to my user list  database in realtime DB. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Authentication works great but the new user is not being added to the DB.

```
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

in the code below, I register them then add their names to the DB and then send a verification email.

```
function handleRegister() {
     var ref = firebase.database().ref();
     console.log(email);
     console.log(fname);

        if (email.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter an email address.');
        return;
      }
      if (password.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter a password.');
        return;
      }

      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {


      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; 
      // [START_EXCLUDE]
      if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
        alert('The password is too weak.');

             firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if(user) {

              var postData = {
                Fullname: fname + lname,
                  email: email,
              };

              // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
              var updates = {};
              updates['/Users/' + uid ] = postData;

              return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

        }
      })
      } else {
         console.log(error);

    }

  })
```

Authentication and send email verification works fine but names are not being added to the DB. Also if there is a better approach to achieve auth,add to DB and send email verification, please let me know. Please help.

This is the updated addition

```
var addusertoDB = function(user){

           var uid = firebase.getAuth().uid;
           var postData = {
            Firstname: fname,
            Lastname: lname,
            email: email,
          }
            // Get a key for a new Post.
          var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('Users').push().uid
          // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
          var updates = {};
          updates['/Users/' + newPostKey] = postData;
          // updates['/user-posts/' + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;
          return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
    }
```

and handle register has been updated to

```
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(


        addusertoDB).catch(handleCreateUserError);
```

it's finally being added to the DB (without the uid) but firebase.getAuth().uid is not getting the uid. the error I'm getting is "firebase.getAuth is not a function"

Comment: `catch()` is used for error handling....you need to do this inside `then()` not `catch()`

Comment: ok, do i replace catch with then?, sorry I'm really new with firebase. can you help post the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to handle both the errors and the user update in the same function you have passed to `catch()`. This means that any code inside that function is only run when `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` fails.

From the firebase documentation:

> **createUserWithEmailAndPassword**
>
> `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` returns
>   `firebase.Promise` containing non-null `firebase.User`
>
> Creates a new user account associated with the specified email address
>   and password.
>
> On successful creation of the user account, this user will also be
>   signed in to your application.

This means that on the successful creation of a user you will have access to the new user via a callback passed into `then()`.

You probably want something like this:

```
var doSomethingWithNewUser = function(user) {
    // Manipulate the newly created User however you like here.
    // You don't have to sign them in again.
};

var handleCreateUserError = function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // Do whatever you want with the error codes.
};

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(doSomethingWithNewUser)
    .catch(handleCreateUserError);
```

Comment: It's unclear to me why it looks like your code tries to update the user entry after they have been created though -- if a user is registered in your system they should already exist in a User table in the database somewhere...